# Unhiding tabs with jquery using text boxes unhides the wrong section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a form that has a few checkboxes and when the boxes are checked, a corresponding tab with a section underneath is unhidden. Unfortunately, when I check the 2nd or 3rd box, the correct tab appears, but the section that belongs to the first tab us unhidden with it. I have an example in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/HyMBD/2/. If you check the box that says Extranet Access, the section for Use Agreement (US 531) appears. Here is the code I am using to unhide my tabs and sections:

```
//hide/show UA Section
        $("#use-agreement-required").click(function() {
            if ($("#use-agreement-required").is(":checked"))
            {
                $(".UASection").show("fast");
            } else {
                //otherwise hide it
                $(".UASection").hide("fast");
            }

        });

        //hide/show Extranet Section
        $("#extranet-access").click(function() {
            if ($("#extranet-access").is(":checked"))
            {
                //show hidden class
                $(".extranetSection").show("fast");

            } else {
                //otherwise hide it
                $(".extranetSection").hide("fast");
            }

        });

        //hide/show Move It Section
        $("#move-it-access").click(function() {
            if ($("#move-it-access").is(":checked"))
            {
                //show hidden class
                $(".moveItSection").show("fast");

            } else {
                //otherwise hide it
                $(".moveItSection").hide("fast");
            }

        });

        //Refresh tabs
        $("#use-agreement-required,#extranet-access,#move-it-access").click(function () {
            $("#contractTypes").tabs("refresh");
        });
```

Comment: It's not specificly a problem with the first tab. That happens after any checkbox is checked, then the corresponding tab clicked.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that tabs are what you want to do there?  From a UI perspective, I think you're heading down a messy path.

That being said, showing the tab isn't enough, you need to tell the tabs control that you are activating a new tab:

$( "#contractTypes" ).tabs({ active: 1 });

Bear in mind, the index is 0 based.

Comment: this is the correct answer. I was too slow, but here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mny7Z/

Comment: This is close... but if you click in this order: Use Agreement - Extranet - Move It - Move It - Extranet - Use Agreement, when you click the Extranet checkbox to deselect it, the Move It Section Reappears even though the Move It checkbox is no longer selected.

Comment: Also, I'm definitely open to suggestions on the UI, but there is a lot more to this form than is on here. This is just one section of the form. It's also worth nothing that this is for a document management system and not a website. Users fill out this form to allow the system to generate Word documents based on the checkbox values and the other fields they fill in on the form. I'm sure UI principles still apply though.

Comment: I found this: http://www.remotesynthesis.com/post.cfm/adding-and-removing-tabs-with-jquery-and-jquery-ui

Once your tab list item has a unique ID, you can simply hide it by using $("#tabs-1-tab").css("display","none") or $("#tabs-1-tab").css("display","list-item") to show it again. One trick in this case is that if you hide the currently selected tab, you will need to refresh the displayed content by deliberately selecting another tab or the content of the closed tab will still show.  ...

Comment: That does require that you figure out which tabs are turned on and select one of those.

Answer (score 0):

This messes up your code ..deleted, all fine

```
//Refresh tabs
$("#use-agreement-required,#extranet-access,#move-it-access").click(function () {
    $("#contractTypes").tabs("refresh");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HyMBD/5/

Comment: I don't know about your browser, but on Chrome, it pushes the contents of the new tab below the contents of the active tab. (select two things at once)

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct fiddle listed?  I don't see the code you're referencing.

Comment: your right ! didn't see it happening in the fiddle since the window is a bit small